# Detect if browser does not support XMLHttpRequest with full CORS support

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, xmlhttprequest, xdomainrequest

How do I check if a browser supports the native JavaScript XMLHttpRequest object with CORS? I am testing in IE 8 which as I understood only supports `XDomainRequest`, however doing the following in IE 8:

```
typeof window.XMLHttpRequest
"object"
```

I would have thought that would be `undefined`. Basically how can I detect if a browser supports the full `XMLHttpRequest` with CORS support?

Should I do the inverse?

```
if(type window.XDomainRequest === 'object') {
    // Assume the browser does not support XMLHttpRequest with CORS
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this, 1 means XMLHttpRequest support cors, 2 means cors is supported via XDomainRequest, 0 means no CORS support

```
var  corsSupportLevel = null;    
function supportsCorsInternal() {

                if (corsSupportLevel !== null) return corsSupportLevel;

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                if (typeof xhr.withCredentials !== 'undefined') {
                    // Supports CORS
                    corsSupportLevel = 1;
                } else if (typeof XDomainRequest !== "undefined") {
                    // IE
                    corsSupportLevel = 2;
                } else {
                    corsSupportLevel = 0;
                }
                return corsSupportLevel;
            }
```